# How to encode NSNetService?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nscoding

I have a class that has these two ivars:

```
@interface UserData : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSString *name;
    NSNetService *service;
}
```

I wanted to encode this into a NSData object eventually, so I implemented NSCoding:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        name = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"] copy];
        service = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"service"] copy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:service forKey:@"service"];
}
```

However, when I try to use `archivedDataWithRootObject` it gives the errors:

> -[NSNetService encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x100170c40
>
> -Exception detected while handling key input.
>   -[NSNetService encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x100170c40
>
> -*** -[NSKeyedArchiver dealloc]: warning: NSKeyedArchiver deallocated
>   without having had -finishEncoding
>   called on it.

How can I make `NSNetService` work with NSCoding?

Comment: Hmm... I may be wrong on this, but I believe NSNetService objects are not supposed to be archived. The point of bonjour is that it gives you information about the state of the available services on the local network _at the time they are created_ as a result to you running an NSNetServiceBrowser. Any time later, there is no guarantee that an NSNetService resolves to anything interesting... hence there's very little use in archiving one of these.